# In Box2D, how can I check for bodies within a circle?

Tags: c++, collision-detection, box2d

I'm trying to sample random positions to find one that is sufficiently far from other bodies.

Hence I'd need to test for bodies within a given circle. So far, I've used `b2World::QueryAABB` around my circle (which does what I want but for a rectangular area), then manually doing an intersection test with all the fixtures it gives me.

It seems to me like Box2D should already provide such functionality—is there a way that lets me do this without reinventing most of the wheel?

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17316722/box2d-check-collision-overlaping-at-any-moment

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest using a sensor.

1. Create a circular body of the size of you choosing at the location you desire.
2. Set the Sensor flag to true.
3. Leave it there for a step. (The delta can be 0 units)
4. See if the sensors isTouching flag is set to true.

[box2d Manual](http://www.box2d.org/manual.html)

> Sometimes game logic needs to know when two fixtures overlap yet there
>   should be no collision response. This is done by using sensors. A
>   sensor is a fixture that detects collision but does not produce a
>   response.
>
> You can flag any fixture as being a sensor. Sensors may be static or
>   dynamic. Remember that you may have multiple fixtures per body and you
>   can have any mix of sensors and solid fixtures.
>
> Sensors do not generate contact points. There are two ways to get the
>   state of a sensor:
>
> 1. b2Contact::IsTouching
> 2. b2ContactListener::BeginContact and EndContact

Comment: If you need to leave the sensor for a step, that's a little tough if you're trying to find a location to place your object: "Is here good? nope... What about here? nope.. etc"

Comment: Yea, especially since I might have to sample a lot of points to actually find one that is free. Can't just leave it there for x steps. Other than that, it's a nice suggestion..

Comment: @John McDonald No need to wait a frame if that's what your implying. Just have a time delta of 0 ms when you do the step. It will update  collision but not move anything.

Comment: Ahh, that makes more sense. Thanks for updating the answer too btw

Answer (score 4):

For completeness, I'll document the "reinventing the wheel" approach.

I recently wanted to do this too, but I wanted to do it statically (due to some code-structure decisions made before that I didn't want to break). So I didn't want to create a sensor body and `World.Step`, [as previously suggested](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/27340/7804).

Instead, I figured that a *convex polygon* intersects with a *circle* if

- some of the polygon's corners are in the circle, or
- a raycast from the center of the circle toward its center hits in the circle

Both can be determined statically, with some simple math and `World.RayCast`.

**For the corners**: Get them by calling `fixture.GetShape().GetVertices()`. Make sure to transform them from the `Body`'s local coordinate space into world coordinates using `body.GetWorldPoint`. Then determine intersection by comparing their distances from the circle center to the circle's radius.

**For the sides**: `RayCast` a vector from the center of the circle toward the center of the tank with the length of the radius. If you get anything, it's a hit.

---

Why you need to check both cases:

If you only check the corners, a side between them might still intersect.

[image: collision with side, but not corners]

If your raycast toward the middle misses, a corner might still intersect.

[image: collision with corner not caught by raycast]

Depending on your objects' relative dimensions and the required precision, doing just one of these could be a good approximation.